# Appending and arc to svg element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to append a svg and arc in it to html page. This is how I tried to do this:

```
<script>
var cityNames=["Челябинск","Область","Миасс","Копейск"];
var cityPercentage=["50%","30%","20%","10%"];
var width=300,
    height=300,
    radius=Math.min(width, height)/2;
var p=Math.PI * 2;
var cityDivision = d3.select("#cities")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class","span4 cityDivision");
var group=cityDivision.append("g")
          .append("transform","translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
var arc=d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius-20)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .starAngle(0)
    .endAngle(p);
group.append("path")
    .attr("d",arc);
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div  id="cities">
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="amount">
            Численность
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="LPU">
            ЛПУ
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason there is an svg element in div with only  element in it. What's wrong? 
P.S. I use [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOu8y51VwMM)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a pie chart. [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1203641) may help.

Comment: I'm trying to do donut chart.

Comment: And [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) is a donut chart.

Comment: I used this example but decided to use video tutroial instead.

Comment: I've added translate according to example that you suggested, but still don't see any bars on my svg. According to video there should be   an full arc (circle).

Comment: You have a typo there (`starAngle`). Also the `transform` needs to be an attribute, not an element. See http://jsfiddle.net/C3REX/

Comment: Lol, transform is attr in my code. Dunno how it came out to be element here). Thanx, that works

Comment: You can write it like an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is a simple typo -- `starAngle` instead of `startAngle`. Also, `transform` should be an attribute, not an element.

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C3REX/).